# Cross apply vs CTE in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

I have two tables
the first table is named: tblprovince

```sql
create table (
    provinceid int not null primary key (1,1) ,
    provinceNme nvarchar(max),
    description nvarchar(max))
```

the second table is named tblcity:

```sql
create table tblcity(
    cityid int identity (1,1), 
    CityName nvarchar(max), 
    population int, 
    provinceid int foreign key references tblprovince(provinceid)
);
```

I need to list all provinces that have at least two large cities. A large city is defined as having a population of at least one million residents. The query must return the following columns:

- tblProvince.ProvinceId
- tblProvince.ProvinceName
- a derived column named LargeCityCount that presents the total count of large cities for the province

```
select p.provinceId, p.provincename, citysummary.LargeCityCount
from tblprovince p 
cross apply ( 
select count(*) as LargeCityCount from tblcity c 
 where c.population >= 1000000 and c.provinceid=p.provinceid
) citysummary 
where citysummary.LargeCityCount
```

Is this query correct?
Are there other methods that allow me to achieve my goal?

Comment: You said 1 million and you typed in 100 000.

Comment: Yep sorry for the careless mistak

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Try and use a spelling checker.

Comment: what about the title CTE vs CROSS APPLY ?

Comment: Could someone edit this title and the tags? There's nothing in here that relates to CTEs or Cross Apply. Also, this really sounds like a homework question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tp.provinceid, tp.provinceNme, COUNT(tc.cityid) AS largecitycount 
FROM tblprovince tp INNER JOIN
tblcity tc ON tc.provinceid=tp.provinceid
WHERE tc.population>=1000000
GROUP BY tp.provinceid, tp.provinceNme
HAVING COUNT(tc.cityid)>1
```